# Typeahead function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

so I'm trying to implement a typeahead functionality to my website but after trying all kinds of stuff I narrowed the problem to the fact that it doesn't respond to the typing in the field. This is my code now:

```
<input id="typeahead" class="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search ..">

<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() {
                        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
                            source: function(query, process){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'php/functions/getSearchResults.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: 'query=' + query,
                                    dataType: 'JSON',
                                    async: true,
                                    success: function(data) {
                                        console.log(data);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

And nothing happens. These are the scripts I have loaded:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Anything I am missing? Thank you!

Comment: You say these are the scripts you have loaded but didn't put anything there. I'm assuming you have a script that adds a typeahead function to the jQuery object?

Comment: UM, why do you have the full and min versions of bootstrap linked? Only add the min. And you can not have an alert in an object.

Comment: Your basic JavaScript syntax is off ... back to the drawing board.

Comment: Okay , I changed the question and added the full function. Before that I put just an alert to simplify things because in my opinion this function is never called but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Don't know what version of Bootstrap you're using, but Bootstrap 3 doesn't have typeahead.

Comment: Read up and install: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/